# How to Use KDE File Chooser In Libreoffice 6.2.2.2?

Tags: libreoffice, kde, openoffice

I changed the file chooser a while back because my version of Libreoffice Writer crashed all the time when I would go to choose a file.

There have been a few versions between then and I would like to try it out without having to purge libreoffice.

Where can I set the file chooser from the image below to the nice KDE style one I had before? I forgot where the setting was.

[image: Old Style File Chooser]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setting was removed from the options menu -- see [the LO 6.0 release notes](https://wiki.documentfoundation.org/ReleaseNotes/6.0#General_3). You can still find it in the expert configuration menu. Go to `LibreOffice` > `General` > `Advanced` > `Open Expert Configuration`. Search for "UseSystemFileDialog" and double click to toggle.

Before I found this, I had written up some other suggestions, which I'll leave below.

---

You haven't stated what VCL plugin is being used. See `Help` > `About LibreOffice`. If it's not using the KDE plugin, I expect that this would affect the file dialogs as well.

Check that you have the relevant package installed. On Ubuntu 18.10, this is `libreoffice-kde5` (or on older versions, `libreoffice-kde`).

Usually the appropriate integration package will be used if installed. If not, check that you haven't set the environment variable OOO_FORCE_DESKTOP (or anything else related to LO) in any dotfiles, as well as the .desktop files for the applications menu. As a final resort, you could set the variable OOO_FORCE_DESKTOP to "kde" (or perhaps "kde5", I'm not sure).

Comment: I found that my Ubuntu 20.04 system 'randomly' flipped over to showing me the Qt file dialog in LibreOffice 7.1.6.2, when what I want/prefer is the Gtk dialog, in common with other programs on my system. Don't know why this happened... but this Expert Configuration option to set `UseSystemFileDialog` to `true` successfully put it back to what I'm used to. Thanks!